# MicroPython - ESP8266 using WebRepl

Tags: esp8266

I'm trying to use WebRepl on an ESP8266 port.

1. Micropython was install OK.
2. @repl : `import webrepl-setup` to initiate WebRepl. OK
3. reboot.
4. connect to AP of ESP8266 port - OK
5. using downloaded `webrepl.html` file to access. OK
6. connect to `192.168.4.1` , including password. OK
7. unable to enter text at prompt....

What is missing?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @SeanHoulihane nnnnnope